# What version of React does a detached Outsystems application use

Tags: reactjs, outsystems

I've inherited a set of solutions.  The system was originally built using OutSystems but then the company I'm contracting with decided to stop using OutSystems.  They were able to get the code from OutSystems.  When that happens Outsystems calls it a detached system.  I see that it's using some version of React but can't find anything online that looks like the code I'm looking at in my inherited solution.

This is the kind of thing I see in the code that I've inherited.  And I just can't find anything about React online that looks like this so I don't know what version it is.  If I could figure that out I think it'd make my google searches more efficient.

```
 React.createElement(OSWidgets.Input, {
    _validationProps: {
        validationService: validationService
    }
    ,
    enabled: true,
    gridProperties: {
        classes: "ThemeGrid_Width11"
    }
    ,
    inputType:/*Text*/ 0,
    mandatory: false,
    maxLength: 50,
    style: "form-control upperinput",
    variable: model.createVariable(someIDNumber, function(value) {
        someIDNumber = value;
    }),
    _idProps: {
        service: idService,
        name: "Input_vIDNumber"
    }
    ,
    _widgetRecordProvider: widgetsRecordProvider
})),
```

Comment: That's just what React looks like after the JSX is turned into actual JS: https://react.dev/reference/react/createElement.

Comment: Depending on the platform version used to genereate the now detached code it uses react 15 (prior to 11.12.0) or React 16 (11.12.0 and onwards) by default.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link @jonrsharpe.  The example I provided is the actual source code I was given and then only one element from a page that has TONS of nested elements (not to mention the model, view and controller all in one JS file - ugh! :) ).  So basically mine looks more like the graphic under the line "Here is a complete example written with createElement:" in the link you gave, not like the graphic under the line "With JSX, it would look like this:".  Wonder if I could feed it through some kind of JSX "pipe" to get it to be more legible? Or maybe I'm still confused?

Comment: Thanks for the version info @MarkBaijens.  I'll see if anyone around here remembers what version of OutSystems they're using.